# Custom function in casbin matcher in pycasbin for restful apis

Tags: python-3.x, casbin

Hi I want to check for roles single or multiple in the matcher for my restful apis endpoint, I am getting roles as list of strings, I want to enfore casbin permission for the endpoints.
How do I create custom function in python, I am not getting any detail for python [here](http://%20https://casbin.org/docs/en/function) (https://casbin.org/docs/en/function)
I am using pycasbin.

my auth_policy:

```
p, custom_role, endpoint, GET
```

in my authz_model.conf, I want to add my `custom_func(p.role,r.role)` instead of  checking `p.role==r.role`

Comment: Plz use `add_function()`, see: https://github.com/casbin/pycasbin/issues/215

Comment: Here's an example: https://github.com/casbin/pycasbin/pull/217

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `add_function()`, see: https://github.com/casbin/pycasbin/issues/215

Here's an example: https://github.com/casbin/pycasbin/pull/217